# Vue 3 How to prevent click event while dragging and dropping the button

Tags: javascript, button, drag-and-drop, click, vuejs3

I made draggable buttons which
users could drag it any where in the screen plus
when we click the button the notice will pop up.
But here is the problem that occurs.
While we are dragging and dropping the buttons, 
it also counts as @click events and the notice 
pops up automatically and I would like to prevent 
@click event in this case. 
Can Anyone please help me?

```
import { ref } from 'vue'
import IconSoundFilled from '~icons/ant-design/sound-filled'
import { useDraggable } from '@vueuse/core'
import PageSubtitle from '../../common/components/Atom/PageSubtitle.vue'
import { useTimestamp } from '@vueuse/core'

const visible = ref<boolean>(false)
const el = ref<HTMLElement | null>(null)

const { x, y, style } = useDraggable(el, {
  initialValue: { x: 500, y: 60 }
})

const noticeList: object[] = [
  {
    title:
      'yo'
  },
  {
    title:
      'yo'
  },
  {
    title:
      'yo'
  },
  {
    title:
      'yo'
  },
  {
    title:
      'yo'
  },
  {
    title:
      'yo'
  }
]

const timestamp = useTimestamp({ offset: 0 })
const date = new Date(timestamp.value)
</script>

<template>
  <button
    ref="el"
    :style="style"
    class="item bg-gray-dark fixed z-10 h-[54px] w-[54px] rounded-full shadow-lg"
    @click="visible = !visible"
  >
    <button
      class="bg-red absolute top-0.5 right-0.5 h-[15px] w-[15px] rounded-full text-xs font-bold text-white"
    >
      1
    </button>
    <div class="flex justify-center">
      <IconSoundFilled class="hover:text-red text-xl text-white" />
    </div>
  </button>
  <div
    v-if="visible"
    class="bg-white-light border-gray fixed h-96 w-4/6 overflow-auto rounded-md border border-solid px-6 py-2"
  >
    <div class="mb-3 flex justify-center">
      <PageSubtitle text="Notice" class="right-auto" />
    </div>
    <div
      v-for="(item, index) in noticeList.slice().reverse()"
      :key="index"
      class="flex gap-6 text-sm"
    >
      <IconSoundFilled v-if="index == 0" class="text-red text-xl" />
      <IconSoundFilled v-else class="text-xl text-black" />
      {{ item.title }}
      {{ date }}
      <br />
      <br />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: I wonder if the issue is that you have a button inside a button - considering a `<button>` element MUST NOT contain ANY *interactive content* (which includes `<button>`) the HTML is technically invalid, so that may be the source of your problem, since dragging doesn't involve a click

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks for your comment! That was the information that I did not know. However, even if I have changed <button> -> <div>, it is still not working as what I have expected :(